# How to combine dictionaries into a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to combine my 3 dictionaries into 1 nested dictionary. I wrote the following code to do it using 3 nested for loops. But is there any efficient way or recursive function to the same thing?

```
X = {"X1":["O","E","P"],"X2":["M"]}
Y = {"O":["a"],"E":["b","c"],"P":["d"],"M":["r"]}
Z = {"a":["1"],"b":["2","3"],"c":[],"d":["4","5"],"r":["6"]}

d1 = {}
for k in X:
    A = X[k]
    d2 = {}
    for v in A:
        B = Y[v]
        d3 = {}
        for i in B:
            C = Z[i]
            d3.update({i:C})
        d2.update({v:d3})
    d1.update({k:d2})
```

Comment: Just to note, you could simplify by using `dict[key] = value` instead of `dict.update({key: value})`, and eliminate names that are only used once (i.e. `A`, `B`, `C`). So `C = Z[i]; d3.update({i: C})` would become `d3[i] = Z[i]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use simple recursion:

```
X = {"X1":["O","E","P"],"X2":["M"]}
Y = {"O":["a"],"E":["b","c"],"P":["d"],"M":["r"]}
Z = {"a":["1"],"b":["2","3"],"c":[],"d":["4","5"],"r":["6"]}
start = [X, Y, Z]
def group(d):
   return d if all(all(c not in i for i in start) for c in d) else \
           {i:group([c[i] for c in start if i in c][0]) for i in d}

r = {a:group(b) for a, b in X.items()}
print(r == d1) #d1 generated from OP's solution
```

Output:

```
{'X1': {'O': {'a': ['1']}, 'E': {'b': ['2', '3'], 'c': []}, 'P': {'d': ['4', '5']}}, 'X2': {'M': {'r': ['6']}}}
True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any useful source to learn recursion?

Comment: @Kevin_ALA Take a look at this [link](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/recursion.html). It has several examples which introduce and explain recursion quite well. Also see [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Recursions/recursions.html) which contains useful example code.

Answer (score 4):

dictionary comprehension for a 1 liner, basically same procedure as your nested for- loop:

```
{k: {v0:{v1: Z[v1] for v1 in Y[v0]} for v0 in v} for k, v in X.items()}
```

outputs:

```
{'X1': {'O': {'a': ['1']},
  'E': {'b': ['2', '3'], 'c': []},
  'P': {'d': ['4', '5']}},
 'X2': {'M': {'r': ['6']}}}
```

explanation:
OP's algorithm looks up the values list in the next dictionary using as keys each of the values in the current list until the last dictionary is reached. *In pseudocode, the nesting looks like:*

```
# pseudo code
for key, values in X
    for valX in values:
        for valY in Y[valX]: # note Y[valX] is a list
            Z[valY]
```

translating this into a comprehension, we start from the inner-most loop, going out & adding the necessary decoration

step 1:

```
{y:Z[y] for ys in Y.values() for y in ys}
# out: 
{'a': ['1'], 'b': ['2', '3'], 'c': [], 'd': ['4', '5'], 'r': ['6']}
```

step 2: now we're looking up the `ys` directly

```
{x:{y:Z[y] for y in Y[x]} for xs in X.values() for x in xs}
# out:
{'O': {'a': ['1']},
 'E': {'b': ['2', '3'], 'c': []},
 'P': {'d': ['4', '5']},
 'M': {'r': ['6']}}
```

step 3: now we put in the keys from `X` & add another layer of dictionary nesting

```
{k:{x:{y:Z[y] for y in Y[x]} for x in xs} for k, xs in X.items()}
```

which yields the desired result

In general, when attempting to convert nested-loops to comprehensions, start from the inner most loop, and work outwards.

Comment: +1 I came up with basically the same thing: `{k: {i: {j: Z[j] for j in Y[i]} for i in X[k]} for k in X}`

Comment: A short explanation of how this works might help :)

Comment: @l'L'l, added an explanation on solution construction